# Automatic point detection

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have a depth image (in blue) and of it, I generate an outline image, where I want to take some points automatically (highlighted in red).

I already have the points (x,y) of the outline, but I would like to pick up the points marked in red automatically.

For this task, I am using python 3.6 (OpenCV ...) and I have a 435i realsense camera that gives me the depth image.

Would it be possible to get an approximate value of these coordinates automatically?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiTvh.png

a small example of the code:

```py
# function tha captures the edges
def get_edges(frame):

    image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)
    _, image = cv2.threshold(image, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    image = cv2.bitwise_not(image)

    element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))

    image = cv2.erode(image, element)
    image = cv2.dilate(image, element)

    image = cv2.Canny(image, 100, 200, L2gradient=True)

    return image

# ... read the frames, process the image ...
image_process = get_edges(depth_frame)

# taking the contour indices
indices = np.where(image_process == 255)

# get coordiniates
coordinates = zip(indices[1], indices[0])
```

My variable "coordinates" has all the points (x,y) of the outline, but I would like to automatically set the points in red highlighted in the image.

Comment: Please post an example image to some free hosting service and put your URL in a comment.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: @fmw42 here is an example of the image

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1frXxb7E8irkZxjZNLPtwyi8NvcmjA2Ud?usp=sharing

Comment: Those red regions are not points. They have area. If you already have the x,y points, then what do you need? I do not understand?  Do you want the centroids of the red regions? Do you want the coordinates for the outlines within the red regions?

Comment: I have to calculate the distance between the points. I want the coordinates for the region in red, automatically capture these points.

Comment: I drew on red dots in hand, just to indicate where I want to get the coordinates automatically

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve using [Pose Estimation](https://github.com/jgraving/DeepPoseKit)

[Final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHOxc.png)

Where I have the return of the points and coordinates:

```py
points = {'A': (67, 121), 'B': (66, 21), 'C': (165, 38), 'D': (133, 143)}
```